# When i extract data from excel sheet using def function in python, i am getting output in single and double quotes ("",'',[])

Tags: python, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When i extract data from excel sheet using def function in python selenium , i am getting output in single and double quotes ("",'',[]). I don't want output in Single or Double Quotes.

Also when i read data from excel sheet in "Gmail Application" using selenium, it reads in single and double quotes.

Can you guys please help me to resolve this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from xlrd import open_workbook
import xlrd
import xlwt



book=xlrd.open_workbook("E:\\Email.xlsx")
print(book.nsheets)
SheetName =book.sheet_by_name("gmail")
rows=SheetName.nrows
cols=SheetName.ncols
def getcell(rows,cols):

    table=list()
    record=list()

    for x in range(rows):
        for y in range(cols):
            record.append(SheetName.cell(x,y).value)    
            table.append(record)
            record=[]
            rows=rows+1

    return table;

v=getcell(1,1)
print(str(v))
```

OUTPUT:

[['abcdefg']]

[['abc@gmail.com']]

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\home\\workspace\\geeko\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.gmail.com/")
elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*@id='identifierId']").send_keys(str(getcell(1, 1)))
```

Comment: Can you try to format your code? Also, can you say exactly what you're reading from the spreadsheet and what's the expected value you want?

Comment: I want output "[['abcdefg']] [['abc@gmail.com']] without single , double quotes or brackets

Comment: I mean i am getting output "[['abcdefg']] [['abc@gmail.com']] with single , double quotes and  brackets . I want o/p without single , double quotes and  brackets

Comment: Please Help....

Comment: Give an example of the contents you have in this spreadsheet. Can you take a screenshot and add to your question? Or maybe write down what is has.

Comment: I have two contents in my spreadsheet.  1st) abcdefg 2nd) abc@gmail.com    so now when i try to extract data , the output is coming in Single , double quotes and brackets.                        [['abcdefg']]
[['abc@gmail.com']]. I want o/p without brackets and without single or double quotes.

Comment: can you not strip them out before adding to the list? or is that what you are asking how to do?

Comment: Just re-read your question again, there is no issue with the data coming from excel. Python represents lists with brackets [] and because you are storing a list within a list you get double brackets, also python represents strings with single quotes. So your output above is perfect normal for python as far as I can tell.

Comment: yes correct, but now when i run below code, the data passed to gmail text box is coming with Single, double quotes. for e.g the data passing to gmail text box is  [['abcdefg']]                                                                                                                                                                            
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\home\\workspace\\geeko\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.gmail.com/")
elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*@id='identifierId']").send_keys(str(getcell(1, 1)))

Comment: are you python 3 by any chance? if so try doing `print(*v, sep='')` where v is your list of course

Comment: nope not working.And i want that when i run the above selenium code , the data passed should not be in single or double quotes.                                       e.g when i run the code, i am getting [['abcdefg']] , i want the same o/p but without single quotes or brackets...as of now i am getting with single quotes and brackets

Answer (score 0):

Ok add this function to your code (note it will concatenate the table together in one string, but you can modify it with any delimiters you need

```
def strip_table(t):
    out_str = ""
    for item in t:
        out_str += str(item[0])

    return out_str
```

Then replace

```
elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*@id='identifierId']").send_keys(str(getcell(1, 1)))
```

with

```
elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*@id='identifierId']").send_keys(strip_table(getcell(1, 1)))
```

Comment: nope not worked. By adding above code, the data passing to gmail text box is null.Also eclipse is not throwing any error message.

Comment: Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Hi CPP, sorry for the long delay, yes please copy and paste the code if you still need help.